# Check the result of HMAC hash on an online HASH Generator

Tags: c, hash, sha1

I'm working on SHA generation and I would like to be sure that the SHA1 I got is OK but I don't know how to check it online.

I have this Input :

```
uint32_t g_ui32RandomData[16] =
{
0xe2bec16b, 0x969f402e, 0x117e3de9, 0x2a179373,
0x578a2dae, 0x9cac031e, 0xac6fb79e, 0x518eaf45,
0x461cc830, 0x11e45ca3, 0x19c1fbe5, 0xef520a1a,
0x45249ff6, 0x179b4fdf, 0x7b412bad, 0x10376ce6
};
```

This HMAC Key :

```
uint32_t g_ui32HMACKey[16] =
{
0x8a5f1b22, 0xcb935d29, 0xcc1ac092, 0x5dad8c9e,
0x6a83b39f, 0x8607dc60, 0xda0ba4d2, 0xf49b0fa2,
0xaf35d524, 0xffa8001d, 0xbcc931e8, 0x4a2c99ef,
0x7fa297ab, 0xab943bae, 0x07c61cc4, 0x47c8627d
};
```

And the result is by performing SHA1 :

```
{0x326e8759, 0xf138cd36, 0xfb44cd58, 0x132b563a 0x76772c4b}
```

How can I enter these values in this website for example :https://www.liavaag.org/English/SHA-Generator/HMAC/

Comment: ? Input type ->hex and copy all the hexes.

Comment: What HMAC key has to do with SHA? HMAC might be using SHA as one of the primitives, but HMAC and SHA are totally not the same thing.

Comment: @KamilCuk got issues when I enter them "like this", you can try :/

Comment: @EugeneSh. currently I have the SHA_MODE which is SHA1 on my HW Accelerator, but I use an additional HMAC Key

Comment: Use for what? SHA is a "simple" unauthenticated hash. HMAC is an authentication scheme (signature).

Comment: @EugeneSh. When you want to generate an HMAC, you use an algorithm, like SHA1, SHA256, etc. You can check on any website that propose to generate HMAC, it will ask you the SHA Variant

Comment: Yes, I know exactly how HMAC works. But your question is about SHA1 implementation, which does not require HMAC and cannot be validated using online HMAC calculator you are linking to. If you want to validate your HMAC implementation, then please remove the SHA1 from the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209108/discussion-between-pierrep-and-eugene-sh).

Comment: Can check here @EugeneSh. https://imgur.com/a/sXlnr8C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved :

Just an inversion of hex was needed.

Input look like this in the online generator to have it work :

```
6bc1bee22e409f96e93d7e117393172aae2d8a571e03ac9c9eb76fac45af8e5130c81c46a35ce411e5fbc1191a0a52eff69f2445df4f9b17ad2b417be66c3710
```